# Constraining a templated method to accept any integral std::chrono::time_point

Tags: c++, datetime, c++20, constrained-templates

Recently I was writing a class that had overloaded `read` methods for various data types.  One of the sets of types I wanted to handle were integral `std::chrono::time_point`s.  For this I wrote the following code:

```cpp
  // Return a timestamp from a chunk at a given offset as if from an
  // integer in network byte order
  template <IsTimePoint T>
  requires std::integral<typename T::rep>
  [[nodiscard]] T read(length_t offset = 0) const {
    return T{typename T::duration{read<typename T::rep>(offset)}};
  }
```

Elsewhere I included a concept for matching `time_point` types:

```
template <typename T>
concept IsTimePoint =
  requires {
    typename T::clock;
    typename T::duration;
    typename T::rep;
    typename T::period;
    requires std::chrono::is_clock_v<typename T::clock>;
    requires std::same_as<T,
                          std::chrono::time_point<typename T::clock,
                            std::chrono::duration<typename T::rep,
                              typename T::period>>>;
  };
```

The code works. My question is whether this was a good way to solve this problem or whether there is a simpler solution that I have overlooked.  Part of the reason for this project is for me to learn C++20, but I often worry that I might be using new techniques because they are new rather than because they are the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a simpler solution. Shamelessly stolen from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032671/idiomatic-way-to-write-concept-that-says-that-type-is-a-stdvector):

```
template<class, template<class...> class>
static constexpr bool is_specialization = false;

template<template<class...> class T, class... Args>
static constexpr bool is_specialization<T<Args...>, T> = true;

template<class T>
concept IsTimePoint = is_specialization<T, std::chrono::time_point>;
```

On the other hand, consider whether you really want to have the low-level function `read()` construct values of these high-level types. The calling code has to know what the type is of the integer that it reads, then it can construct an appropriate `std::chrono::time_point` from it itself.